# Jump behavior when collapsing navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, navbar

I have a navbar which when collapsing, i'm attempting to ensure the options appear below the border-bottom line i've added. I do this by adding padding to the collapse class. They do appear there but not before a quick jump where it first appears in it's original position (half-way above the line) and then it quickly applies the padding i've added to appear where I want it to, below the line. How Can i remove this quick jump it does?

```css
.navbar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {

.collapse  {
  padding-top: 50px !important;

}

}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-custom">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi-building"></i> Our Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="bi-person-circle"></i> Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I added "transition:none;" but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I don't get your problem. When is the jump happening exactly? On page load?